# When compiling, cline between the coloured cell doesn't appear

Tags: tables

I'm compiling this code and as result I have this table:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
\toprule
                                                                                      &                                                              & \textbf{$\mathcal{J}$ fairness index}           & \textbf{TB size}                                \\
\midrule
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} $16 \times 8$} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} } \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}BLIND\\ METHOD\end{tabular}}}     & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        \\ \midrule
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}$16 \times 8$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}TRAINING\\ METHOD\end{tabular}}}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        \\ \midrule
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}$16 \times 8$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}HEURISTIC\\ METHOD\end{tabular}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{•}
\label{tab_fairness_los}
\end{table}
```

I would like to know how I can make the cline between coloured cells appear? Any idea? Is there something wrong in the code? Do I need a particular package?

If I use `\hline` instead of `\cline` this is what happens: [image]
Sincerely I don't know how I should write

Comment: and `colortbl` package documentations says: `% \section{Less fun with \cs{cline}}
% Lines produced by "\cline"  are coloured if you use
% "\arrayrulecolor" but you may not notice as they are covered up by
% any colour pannels in the following row. This is a \`feature' of
% "\cline". If using this package you would probably better using the
% "-"  rule type in a "\hhline" argument, rather than "\cline"`

Comment: don't use `[h!]` generally it just makes latex give a warning that it is changing it to `ht` but it is almost always best to include `p` as well, otherwise the float is very restricted and more likely to go to the end of the docuemnt as it has no legal place to go.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using this package: `%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}`. I try to use `\hhline` but nothing change.

Comment: If you have a version with hhline that overprints (even when you zoom in) then edit the question to show that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edit, but I don't know how I should write down the changes you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use package `hhline` (add `\usepackage{hhline}`) and use `\hhline{~-|-|-}` instead of your `\cline{2-4}`.  In the documentation of package `hhline` (use `texdoc hhline` on your terminal) you can find: `~` for no line and `-` for a line in the column ...

But just a remark: Why do you use lines and colored cells?  Your colored cells marks very well what you want, you really do not need the lines in the table here.  A **good** typography for tables is to use as less as you can. Start with no vertical lines ...

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
\toprule
                                                                                      &                                                              & \textbf{$\mathcal{J}$ fairness index}           & \textbf{TB size}                                \\
\midrule
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} $16 \times 8$} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} } \\ \hhline{~-|-|-} 
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        \\ \hhline{~-|-|-} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}BLIND\\ METHOD\end{tabular}}}     & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        \\ \midrule
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}$16 \times 8$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        \\ \hhline{~-|-|-} 
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        \\ \hhline{~-|-|-} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}TRAINING\\ METHOD\end{tabular}}}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        \\ \midrule
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}$16 \times 8$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}                        \\ \hhline{~-|-|-} 
                                                                                      & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                        \\ \hhline{~-|-|-} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}HEURISTIC\\ METHOD\end{tabular}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$                         & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}                        \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{•}
\label{tab_fairness_los}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @Mattia Ups, I oversaw two leading `|` in the `\hhline` commands.  Please change `\hhline{|~|-|-|-}` to `\hhline{~-|-|-}` (delete the two leading `|`). Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, with a simplified code,thanks to the  `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in cells and a common formatting.

Also, `booktabs` produces white strips in coloured rows due to its vertical padding of rules. So I propose to use instead the small `boldline` package (from the `shipunov` bundle) and add some vertical padding above and below rows with the `cellspace` package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline, makecell}
\renewcommand\cellset{\bfseries}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cSc|Sc|c}
\hlineB{2.4}%
& &$\bm{\mathcal{J}}$ \textbf{fairness index} & \textbf{TB size} \\
\hlineB{1.5}%
& \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} $16 \times 8$} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}{\color[HTML]{000000} } \\
\hhline{~---} %
& \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\\
\hhline{~---} %
\multirowcell{-3}{BLIND\\ METHOD}& \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \\
\hlineB{1.5}%
& \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}$16 \times 8$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\\
\hhline{~---} %
& \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\\
\hhline{~---} %
\multirowcell{-3}{TRAINING\\ METHOD} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \\
\hlineB{1.5}%\midrule
& \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}$16 \times 8$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\\
\hhline{~---} %
& \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}$16 \times 4$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\\
\hhline{~---} %
\multirowcell{-3}{HEURISTIC\\ METHOD} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$4 \times 4$ & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} & \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \\
\hlineB{2.4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{•}
\label{tab_fairness_los}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard, but I think that the other solution works better. Thanks anyway for the effort.